# JavaScript Module Pattern - How can I get a constructor/init function to fire before the object/function is used?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking up JavaScript patterns to get started on.  I know enough JavaScript to be dangerous, but not enough to be a good architect.

I started by using the module pattern to create a "Model" for managing some Interest data.  With the code below, how can I get a "constructor" method (or some sort of init method to fire) to initalize data when it's used.  This data would be used across all instances, so I'm guessing I would use prototype?

```
var InterestDataModel = (function () {

    // Private
    var interestModels = [];

    return {
        getInterestModels: function () {
            return interestModels;
        },

        resetInterestModels: function () {
            interestModels.length = 0;
        }
    }; // end return
})();

// Calling code
// When this call is made, I want some initialization to be done already!
InterestDataModel.getInterestModels();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're self executing the 'InterestDataModel' function anything inside of that function will be the initialization and run before you call the getInterestModels method.  See this jsfiddle example:  http://jsfiddle.net/rjrqb/1/